# Parameter index indication without using a Set

Tags: pyomo

Is there a way to index a parameter in Pyomo without creating a set,through the Param() function? Is it possible to do it via **validate** for example?

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to create a Set object or use a built in container like a list. E.g.,

```
m.s = Set(initialize=[1,2,3])
m.p = Param(m.s)
```

or

```
m.p = Param([1,2,3])
```

If you do it the second way, then Pyomo will automatically create a Set object and add it to your model with the name `p_index`.